# Change column to HTML type with import.io web extractor

Tags: import.io

I see several tutorials showing how to change the column type when creating a new extractor with import.io, however none of them seem to match the newest version.  I was able to change the column type using the legacy desktop app, however wasn't able to ever publish the extractor.  I assumed because the desktop app is now deprecated.

In the new web extractor I see no way to change the column type. Thus I get the content of the div I'm trying to scrape, but I'm wanting the div contents including all HTML.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi Andy, we just released a new version of Import.io and the ability to set data type is not yet available in this version.  Go and vote on this idea here and then you will get an email notification when this feature is available again. http://support.import.io/forums/199278-ideas-forum/suggestions/13381848-data-type-support-in-new-version-of-import-io Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: ok. thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @andrew-fogg for pointing out that this is not yet available. http://support.import.io/forums/199278-ideas-forum/suggestions/13381848-data-type-support-in-new-version-of-import-io